# Why is quarto not rendering in-line code?

Tags: r, quarto

If I use in-line code in a Quarto document, after rendering the code is displayed as-is and not evaluated. Here the code in the file "mytest.qmd":

````
---
title: "Untitled"
---


```{r}
radius <- 2
```

The radius is `{r} radius`
````

Information on my system

```
RStudio Version
--------------------------------------------------
2023.12.1+402


Session Information
--------------------------------------------------
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22635)
```

Comment: If you're (implicitly) using `knitr`, the syntax is `r radius`.  See [here](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/inline-code.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different notation `r`  instead of `{r}`  like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
---


```{r}
radius <- 2
```

The radius is `r radius`
````

Output:

[image]

## Quarto v1.4

With the latest version of [Quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/blog/posts/2024-01-24-1.4-release/) you can use the notation in your example like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
---


```{r}
radius <- 2
```

The radius is `{r} radius`
````

You probably need to upgrade your Quarto version.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that you have to update Quarto. I assumed it would be updated when installing a newer version of RStudio (I just found that this will be the case in the future). Thanks!